# Number of transactions in binary and the stern's diatomic series

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

From Indian Olympiad Qualifier in Mathematics 2023
[image]

While solving this problem for the general case '$n$' I found this sequence is related to the stern's diatomic series. Can somebody show that the number of ways one can give a change of '$n$' rupees is the nth term of this sequence.

> PS I am a $11$th grader so please don't use stuff which is way up my level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make 100 Bens, so the total amount of change needs to be even. This means you can have either zero $1$-Ben notes, or you can have two $1$-Ben notes.

In the first case, you need to make change for $100$ Bens using only $2,4,8,\dots,$ Ben notes. Dividing everything by $2$, this is equivalent to making change for $50$ Bens using $1,2,4,8,\dots$ Ben notes. Therefore, we have reduced the original problem (100) to a smaller problem (50), so we made progress.

In the other case, you already have two $1$-Ben notes, so you need to make change for $98$ with $2,4,8,\dots,$ Ben notes. This is equivalent to making change for $49$ with the full set of Ben notes.

Let $a(n)$ be the number of ways to make change for $n$ using $1,2,4,\dots,$ Ben notes. The same logic as before, applied to making change for  $2n$, implies the following recurrence:
$$
{\bf Rule} \;1: a(2n)=a(n)+a(n-1),\qquad \text{for all integers $n>0$}
$$
What about for odd numbers? This time, there must be exactly one $1$-Ben note, so we instead get
$$
{\bf Rule} \;2: a(2n+1)=a(n),\qquad \text{for all integers $n>0$}
$$
You can then compute $a(100)$, using a minimal amount of work, by applying the two rules as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
a(100)
&=a(50)+a(49)
\\&= a(25)+a(24)+a(24)=a(25)+2a(24)
\\&=a(12)+2\Big(a(12)+a(11)\Big)=3a(12)+2a(11)
\\&=3\Big(a(6)+a(5)\Big)+2\Big(a(5)\Big)=3a(6)+5a(5)
\\&= 3(a(3)+a(2))+5a(2)=3a(3)+8a(2)
\end{align}
$$
At this point, it is pretty easy to calculate $a(3)=1$ and $a(2)=2$, from which we conclude $a(100)=19$.